# How to hide the Delphi compiler messages that aren't related to warnings and hints?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE4 but the problem should happens in much earlier version of Delphi IDE.  When compile a project group that contain more than 100+ projects, the `Messages` window show something like this:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.core.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.datamap.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.db.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.module.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.styles.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.images.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.script.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.report.fastreport.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQL.Alpha.resource.report.reportbuilder.dproj (Debug, Win32)
Building SQLAlpha.dproj (Debug, Win32)
[dcc32 Hint] SQLAlpha.dpr(10): H2164 Variable 'k' is declared but never used in 'SQLAlpha'
Success
Elapsed time: 00:00:02.0
```

It is getting harder to identify Hints and Warnings from the windows when the list is growing.  The `Building...` messages always show when compile the projects.

Comment: That may be interesting for you. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Warning_messages_(Delphi)

Comment: @Polymorphin: I am aware of that but my problem isn't related to it.

Comment: I have raised an enhancement request: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117527

Comment: Don't auto close the build/compile window (there is a check box in the lower left "Close this window on successful compile" (or something like that). You will have to dismiss the build dialog manually then, but the advantage is that you get the (total?) hints/warnings/errors count so you can ignore / don't have to scan the message window when there are none.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: The summary total of warnings and hints in compiling status windows help but if there are warnings and hints, it is not handy to find the warnings/hints if there are many packages compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no option available in the IDE to filter the messages window. You will probably have to look for a third-party solution.